# Joining all the keys of a list of rules that point to matching values

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

Suppose I have a list of rules whose keys are not of identical structure (in my case, the keys are either lists of at least one symbol or symbols alone):

```
rules = {{a} -> 1, {b, c} -> 1, d -> 2, {e, f} -> 2, {g, g} -> 3, g -> 4};
```

The aim is to get all keys with matching values grouped together to end up with

```
newRules = {{a, b, c} -> 1, {d, e, f} -> 2, {g, g} -> 3, {g} -> 4};
```

I have what seems to me to be a hacky attempt to do this:

```
Reverse /@
    Normal[
        Merge[
            Association /@ Reverse /@ rules, Flatten]
        ] == newRules
(* True *)
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: You could use `Flatten[#[[;; , 1]]] -> #[[1, 2]] & /@ GatherBy[rules, Last]`.

Comment: equally hacky, but different:  ```GroupBy[List @@@ rules, Last -> Most, 
  Flatten] // GeneralUtilities`AssociationInvert```

Comment: `Reverse[Normal[GroupBy[rules, Last -> First, Flatten]], 2]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways, here's one:

```
KeyValueMap[#2 -> # &] @ GroupBy[rules, Last -> First, Flatten]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Reverse /@ (Flatten /@ PositionIndex[Association@rules] // Normal)
```

> {{a, b, c} -> 1, {d, e, f} -> 2, {g, g} -> 3, {g} -> 4}

In addition:

```
Flatten /@ PositionIndex[Association@rules]
```

> <|1 -> {a, b, c}, 2 -> {d, e, f}, 3 -> {g, g}, 4 -> {g}|>

Answer (score 4):

```
KeyValueMap[#2 -> #&] @ Merge[Flatten][Reverse /@ rules]
```

> {{a, b, c} -> 1, {d, e, f} -> 2, {g, g} -> 3, {g} -> 4}

Als0

```
Flatten[#[[All, 1]]] -> #[[1, -1]]& /@ GatherBy[rules, Last]
```

> {{a, b, c} -> 1, {d, e, f} -> 2, {g, g} -> 3, {g} -> 4}

and

```
Values @ GroupBy[rules, Last, Flatten @ #[[All, 1]] -> #[[1, -1]]&]
```

> {{a, b, c} -> 1, {d, e, f} -> 2, {g, g} -> 3, {g} -> 4}

Answer (score 4):

```
Reap[Sow @@@ (List @@@ rules), _, Flatten[{#2}] -> #1 &][[-1]]
```

yields:

```
{{a, b, c} -> 1, {d, e, f} -> 2, {g, g} -> 3, {g} -> 4}
```